# Routing in SveltKit

Tags: routes, svelte, sveltekit

I'm getting a 404 error while trying to access `domainname/about/about2` in SvelteKit. Do I have to create a folder for each page I want to add inside the about folder or am I missing something?

My folder structure looks like this:

```
src/
|-- routes/
    |-- about/
        |-- index.svelte 
        |-- about2.svelte
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example uses sveltekit's old routing system. With the new routing system, you use `+page.svelte` to define a page in a route. If you want to continue using the old method of routing, you will have to create an `about2` folder and put an `index.svelte` file in there. Using the new routing method, your project will look like this:

```
src/
|-- routes/
    |-- about/
        |-- +page.svelte 
        |-- about2/
            |-- +page.svelte
```

Comment: That means if I have 10 different pages inside about folder, then I'll have to create 10 folders inside about main folder; one folder to each page.

Comment: Yeah, you will have to create a folder for each route. I think that it might be a bit annoying, but it will help your project look more organized.

Answer (score 2):

You need one folder per route and very specific file names, read [the routing docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing).